# after getting date from java in date format how to compare it with the input date in java netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, database-connection, database-connectivity

After getting date from MYSQL through results in java in date format how to compare it with the date taken as string from a jtextbox in java netbeans ?

Comment: Although you need to show us the code or result which you getting date from mysql with it, have you tried something or just a little searched it before asking!?!?

Comment: yea.. first i got date as string through textfield then I used jdbc connectivity to get date from mysql as -- Date d=rs.getDate("date");--- and now i want to check whether Date d is equal to jtextfielddate.getText() or not . Please help me out I got a project to submit . @FarhangAmary

Comment: Ok, so edit the question and write the things you mentioned in comment, inside question. I posted an answer, check it

Answer (score 0):

depends on the date format which in the `TextField` you can get the date using `DateFormat` like this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");//put prefer format indide it
Date d1 = format.parse(jtextfielddate.getText());
```

now you can compare it with the date which you retrieved from database(`Date d=rs.getDate("date");`) easily:

```
if(d1==d)
{
  //do something
}
```